# shell script or grunt tool to delete lines in a file, following a rule

Tags: bash, shell, gruntjs, sh

Ok, so i have a huge file that results in the concatenation of a lot of files.

Not that it matters, but it's a compilation of 3 google-closure dependency files, and a lot of unit testing files.

My problem is that each unit test file is requiring some closure modules and because they are now all in the same file the same dependencies are being required more than once when i run it with phantomjs.
What i need is a script that goes through the file, and deletes the lines (after the first) that are repeated and start with `goog.require`(.

So, the rules are:

- starts with `goog.require(`
- the exact same line (ignoring trailing and preceding spaces) exists somewhere before

Example:

```
goog.provide( "app.tests.mvc.PMVCUnitTestBootstrap" );

goog.require( "app.tests.mvc.jsunit" );
goog.require( "app.Bootstrap" );
goog.require( "pmvc.patterns.observer.Observer" );
goog.require( "app.tests.mvc.ApplicationResources" );
goog.require( "app.notifications.SystemNotes" );
goog.require( "lib.puremvc.definitions.notifications.NotificationMapper" );
goog.require( "lib.puremvc.definitions.notifications.NotificationMap" );
...
...
...
goog.require( "app.tests.mvc.jsunit" ); //this line is repeated
goog.require( "app.Bootstrap" ); //this line is repeated
goog.require( "lib.unittests.helpers.ExpectedFailures" );
goog.require( "lib.filesystem.ConstructableFile" );
goog.require( "lib.filesystem.FileReference" );
goog.require( "lib.utils.ArrayUtil" );
goog.require( "easy.util.GUIDUtil" );
...
...
```

would become

```
 goog.provide( "app.tests.mvc.PMVCUnitTestBootstrap" );

 goog.require( "app.tests.mvc.jsunit" );
 goog.require( "app.Bootstrap" );
 goog.require( "pmvc.patterns.observer.Observer" );
 goog.require( "app.tests.mvc.ApplicationResources" );
 goog.require( "app.notifications.SystemNotes" );
 goog.require( "lib.puremvc.definitions.notifications.NotificationMapper" );
 goog.require( "lib.puremvc.definitions.notifications.NotificationMap" );
 ...
 ...
 ...
 goog.require( "lib.unittests.helpers.ExpectedFailures" );
 goog.require( "lib.filesystem.ConstructableFile" );
 goog.require( "lib.filesystem.FileReference" );
 goog.require( "lib.utils.ArrayUtil" );
 goog.require( "easy.util.GUIDUtil" );
 ...
 ...
```

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 1):

Get all unique strings starting with goog.require

```
grep '^goog.require' yourfile.txt | sort -u > uniq_require.txt
```

Then delete all goog.require from source

```
sed -i '/^goog.require/d' yourfile.txt
```

Then concatenate results

```
cat uniq_require.txt yourfile.txt > result.txt
```

Not tested, just a scratch.

Comment: I'll test it myself. be back soon :)

Comment: sed: 1: "build/tmp/all_the_tests.js": undefined label 'uild/tmp/all_the_tests.js'

Comment: How did you invoke it?

Comment: sed -i "/^goog.require/d" build/tmp/all_the_tests.js

Comment: if i run sed "/^goog.require/d" -i build/tmp/all_the_tests.js   it shows me the result but doesn't alter the file

Comment: It seems your sed does not threat build/tmp/all_the_tests.js as a file but tries to run it as a string containing script. Your sed seems different with mine in handling parameters.

Comment: thanks (i'm working with OSX), i think i can do that with grunt-replace and then grunt-concat. the first line works and that's all i need